# c# Image transform to parallelogram

Tags: c#, image, 3d, transform, isometric

Quick question, and is probably a simple answer. I have a square image but I want to squish it so that it is a parallelogram (this is so I can draw some cubes isometrically)

I currently have my images stored in an `Image` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful:
http://www.vcskicks.com/image-distortion.php

This code squishes an image into any quadrangle, not just a parallelogram.

Comment: SO this started me on a journey that ultimately ended up here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03.aspx . I am cautious about using the image-distortion class, because it warned that it was VERY SLOW.

Comment: I wrote some image processing the other day, and I discovered that if you store your image data in an USHORT array and using pointer arithmetic (unsafe code) to manuipulate it, this is REALLY fast, nearly realtime on megapixel images. Surprisingly it is faster than doing this in an unmanaged C++ class, what I also tried. So if you only need to quish an image into a parallelogram it can't be that hart to code. Just use a Bresenham line algorithm to move the rows of the source image to the new position. If you need some example code on pointer arithmetics, just drop ma a note.

Comment: I've done pointer arithmetic before but only in c++. I assume its the same. But as a design choice, what do you think about encapsulating the (unsafe) squash code into a dll, then I don't need to have unsafe code on for my main project.